# android BLE, When advertising or scan response in peripheral mode How do I set up a Txadd and Rxadd?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

How do I set up an android Txadd and RxAdd in the peripheral mode?

TxAdd and RxAdd will have on the bluetooth mac address.

A detailed description of TxAdd and RxAdd , please refer to the link.
http://j2abro.blogspot.kr/2014/06/understanding-bluetooth-advertising.html

thanks.

Comment: That link is not the best source of information. It contains many inaccuracies, and at some point the author states "it's unclear to him what some fields are for", which says something about the article's quality.

Answer (score 0):

TxAdd is automatically set to 1 because Android phones use Private Addresses.
The RxAdd field only matters for directed advertisements, which I don't think you ever use.